# Using nested keys in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I have the following keys that I am unable to access from my NSDictionary:

```
 branches =         (
                        {
                city = "Las Vegas";
                country = "United States";
                countryIsoCode = USA;
                distanceInKms = "19.35";
                distanceInMiles = "12.02";
                id = 16040146;
                latitude = "36.145622";
                longitude = "-115.299103";
                name = "Las Vegas - 89117";
                state = Nevada;
                stateIsoCode = NV;
                street = "9330 W Sahara Ave.";
                telephone = "";
            }
        );
        id = 106699;
        logoUrl = "http://d2bvnbhf12ry1m.cloudfront.net/32636.png";
        name = "Sumits Yoga";
    },
```

I tried using the NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary allKeys]); and I only end up with the following:

```
    feedSources,
    deals,
    errorCode,
    ack,
    timestamp,
    owners,
    version,
    categories,
    currentCount,
    merchants,
    errorMessage,
    referencePoint,
    queryString,
    totalCount
)
```

None of which are the keys and values that I need for instance: "latitude" and "longitude".
How would I access these values and convert them into NSString and NSNumber so that I can store them?

Comment: Can you add the full dictionary to your question so that the hierarchy becomes clear

Comment: It's not "nested keys", it's "nested dictionaries".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just have nested dictionaries, which you would access like so:

```
branches[geoData][latitude]
```

Are you certain this is an NSDictionary and not an object returned by JSON deserialization? The 2 code blocks don't match in any way, so it's difficult to give you a better answer. Are `branches` and `dictionary` the same object?

Comment: I was able to access the values I needed with the following:   NSLog(@"%@", [_result valueForKeyPath:@"merchants.branches.latitude"]);
                 NSLog(@"%@", [_result valueForKeyPath:@"merchants.branches.longitude"]);